# Is there a way to initiate a fully automated app installation from with in Android?

Tags: android, installation, in-app

Is it possible to initiate a fully automated app installation (after a user clicked a "Install app" button)?
Or do I simply have to open the respective Google Play page in the browser, and the user has to handle installation from Google Play as usual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It is impossible to install apps from the API without user intervention.  There are a number of reasons for this, you could perform privilege escalation, to mention one.  Instead, you just have to redirect the user to the Google Play app.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thought there might be an mechanism, which asks the user inside the app about privileges etc...